# How to force Swagger Codegen to generate an enum which is not referenced from any other object?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have an OpenAPI spec with multiple enums:

```yaml
SocialLinkType:
  type: string
  enum:
    - FACEBOOK
    - YOUTUBE
    - INSTAGRAM
    - TWITTER
    - PINTEREST
    - LINKEDIN
    - TIKTOK
    - TUMBLR
    - WHATSAPP
    - VIMEO
    - SNAPCHAT
    - APPLE
    - ANDROID

ColorType:
  type: string
  enum:
    - ACCENT_1
    - ACCENT_2
    - BACKGROUND_1
    - BACKGROUND_2
    - TEXT
    - SOLID_BUTTON
    - OUTLINE_BUTTON
```

The issue I'm facing is about `ColorType`. Unlike `SocialLinkType` it is not referenced from any other component described in OpenAPI spec. As a result `ColorType` Java enum is not generated, so my question is about forcing Swagger Codegen to generate Java code for every item in the spec.

Can this be achieved somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've solved the issue by moving the declaration of `ColorType` into top-level `components` section.
Prior to fix I had only `securitySchemes` declaration under the section:

```yaml
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearer:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
```

I've changed it to

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    ColorType:
      type: string
      enum:
        - ACCENT_1
        - ACCENT_2
        - BACKGROUND_1
        - BACKGROUND_2
        - TEXT
        - SOLID_BUTTON
        - OUTLINE_BUTTON
  securitySchemes:
    bearer:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
```

This gave me desired Java enum among generated classes:

```java
public enum ColorType {
  ACCENT_1("ACCENT_1"),
  ACCENT_2("ACCENT_2"),
  BACKGROUND_1("BACKGROUND_1"),
  BACKGROUND_2("BACKGROUND_2"),
  TEXT("TEXT"), 
  SOLID_BUTTON("SOLID_BUTTON"),
  OUTLINE_BUTTON("OUTLINE_BUTTON");

  private String value;

  ColorType(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  @JsonValue
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static ColorType fromValue(String value) {
    for (ColorType b : ColorType.values()) {
      if (b.value.equals(value)) {
        return b;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
  }
}
```